# partial fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$\frac{1}{1-x^2}$$

$$\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\frac{a}{1-x}+\frac{b}{1+x}$$

$$1=a+ax+b-bx$$

$$1=a+b+x(a-b)$$

$a+b=1$ and $x(a-b)=0\Rightarrow a-b=0\Rightarrow a=b$

$$2a=1\Rightarrow a=\frac{1}{2}$$

$b=\frac{1}{2}$

$$\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\frac{1}{2(1-x)}+\frac{1}{2(1+x)}$$

Where I went wrong?

Comment: You didn't! It's fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't do anything wrong.

$$\frac{1}{1-x^2} = \frac{1}{2(x+1)} - \frac{1}{2(x-1)}$$
is equivalent to your answer of
$$\frac{1}{1-x^2} = \frac{1}{2(1-x)} + \frac{1}{2(1+x)}.$$

I think we can agree that both answers have a common term of $\dfrac{1}{2(1+x)}$.  Now, notice:
$$\frac{1}{2(1-x)} = \frac{1}{2 \cdot [-1(x-1)]} = \frac{1}{-2(x-1)} = -\frac{1}{2(x-1)}$$

Therefore $-\dfrac{1}{2(x-1)} = \dfrac{1}{2(1-x)}$, and so the answers are the same.

Comment: Just out of my own curiosity, You satisfied (with a nice explanation) gbox's question by showing the two answers are equivalent, but the other answer is mentioned nowhere in the question or even elsewhere in this thread as it exists now. How did you know that his question related to this "other answer" ?

Comment: Once I realized gbox's answer was correct, I just guessed based on common mistakes I saw back in my teaching days.

Answer (score 3):

> Notice:
>
> - $$\frac{1}{1-x^2}=\frac{1}{-(x-1)(x+1)}=-\frac{1}{(x-1)(x+1)}$$

So, we get:

$$-\frac{1}{(x-1)(x+1)}=-\frac{a}{x-1}-\frac{b}{x+1}$$

And, now we can see that:

$$a(x+1)+b(x-1)=1\Longleftrightarrow a-b+(a+b)x=1$$

So, we get:

- $$a-b=1\Longleftrightarrow a=b+1\Longleftrightarrow a=-\frac{1}{2}+1=\frac{1}{2}$$
- $$a+b=0\Longleftrightarrow b+1+b=0\Longleftrightarrow 2b=-1\Longleftrightarrow b=-\frac{1}{2}$$

So, now we have the partial fractions:

$$\frac{1}{1-x^2}=-\frac{\frac{1}{2}}{x-1}-\frac{-\frac{1}{2}}{x+1}=\frac{1}{2(x+1)}-\frac{1}{2(x-1)}$$

Comment: but $1-x^2=(1-x)(1+x)$

Comment: @gbox Now, you'll see!

Answer (score 2):

But you are not wrong.

$$\frac{1}{2(1-x)}+\frac{1}{2(1+x)} = \frac{1+x+1-x}{2(1+x)(1-x)} = \frac{2}{2(1+x)(1-x)} = \frac{1}{1-x^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Whats the problem take $1/2$ common so you get $1/2(\frac{1+x+1-x}{1-x^2})=\frac{2}{2(1-x^2)}=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$